# Ckeditor "Convert the HTMLField to a Placeholderfield and configure the placeholder to only accept TextPlugin"

Tags: django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

Perhaps I do not understand some simple thing. I’m reading the documentation for the second day and don’t understand how to use ckeditor in django-cms, in a third-party plugin.

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/djangocms-text-ckeditor/) is written:

> Usage as a model field If you want to use the widget on your own model
>   fields, you can! Just import the provided HTMLField like so:
>
> `from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField` And use it in
>   your models, just like a TextField:
>
> `class MyModel(models.Model):`
>       `myfield = HTMLField(blank=True)` This field does not allow you to embed any other CMS plugins within the text editor. Plugins can only
>   be embedded within Placeholder fields.
>
> If you need to allow additional plugins to be embedded in a HTML
>   field, convert the HTMLField to a Placeholderfield and configure the
>   placeholder to only accept TextPlugin. For more information on using
>   placeholders outside of the CMS see:
>
> http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html

Currently HTMLField is working and after reading the instructions I don’t understand how I can "convert the HTMLfield to a Placeholder and configure the  placeholder to only accept TextPlugin" in a third party plugin which was fully integrated into django-cms. I have never created placeholders in third party plugins.

My goal is so that in a third party plugin I can set a text box in which I can edit the text using formatting features. I am using the latest Django-CMS. By default, it has djangocms_text_ckeditor.

Thank you!

models.py:

```
[..]

    from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

    class Question(models.Model):
    content = HTMLField(blank=True)
[..]
```

template

```
[..]
{% load cms_tags %}
[..]


    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

[..]
```

My textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" class="CMS_CKEditor" data-ckeditor-basepath="/static/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/" id="id_content"></textarea>
```

I noticed that through the admin panel it was possible to use the editor for this new textarea, but nothing has changed on the site for a user.  Visually it is an ordinary textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to include the "{{ form.media }}" tag in the templates

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    [..]
```